# SSL: Hosting images on different host

Tags: ssl, https

Lets say I have bought a domain: `mysupersite.com`
I then buy a SSL sertificate for this domain so that I can access the site through https and present the user with a 'green addressbar'.

Now, I want to move all my picture over to Azure blob storage. Azure blob storage doesn't let me upload my own certificate, so I have to accept the microsoft provided certificate.

So now, my html is loaded from https://mysupersite.com/index.html, and the images on that page from https://mysupersite.blob.core.windows.net/myimage.png

Is this OK?
Will I still get the 'green addressbar' in the browser, or will I get warnings that some content is loaded from a different domain with a different certificate?

Comment: Yes, you will get the green address bar (as its from the domain serving the page) and no "mixed content" security warnings as everything is HTTPS.

Comment: Related to Alex's comments: [Upgrading HTTPS in mid-air:
An empirical study of strict transport security and key pinning](http://jbonneau.com/doc/KB14-hsts_pinning_survey_working_draft.pdf).

Comment: Before I read all 15 pages... How exactly is this related? Does it explain why the address bar will remain green? Or does it describe a security issue related to loading images from different domain, or...?

Comment: @Vegar - sorry, please forget that I mentioned it as related reading.